# Why are my optional variables becoming null after view did appear is called?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am currently working on a Swift app and ran into the problem where the data I am using within the app is becoming nil at a certain point while running. I am having a problem where the data I am creating exists temporarily, and then seems to be deallocated once the screen has finished displaying. While I could reload the data every time I needed it, that seems like the least efficient way to go about it. Here is a code sample of what is happening:

```
var activeProgram:LumeProgram? { didSet{
    if let _ = activeProgram {
        print("activeProgram exists")
    } else {
        print("activeProgram doesn't exists")
    }
} } // Custom Object Type
var activeDay:LumeProgramDay? // Custom Object Type

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    activeProgram = SomeProgram.initTestProgram()
    activeDay = activeProgram!.getCurrentDay()

    printVariables("ViewWillAppear")
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

   printVariables("ViewDidAppear")
}
```

Once this code is called, I see that the data exists for viewWillAppear but not viewDidAppear. Does anyone know what could cause this?

ViewWillAppear Output:

```
--- ViewWillAppear ---
Optional("Nutrition Program") [None]
Phase [Optional(1)]: Optional("Learn") - Optional("Welcome - we’re glad you’re here! Our current focus is learning about your diet. What have you eaten today?")
Lume Program Day: Optional(2)
Main [Insight]: Optional("Day_14_insight.xml")
Sub [None]: nil
Lume Program Day: Optional(1)
Main [Article]: Optional("Day_13_article.xml")
Sub [Quiz]: Optional("Day_13_quiz.xml")
Lume Program Day: Optional(3)
Main [Article]: Optional("Day_15_article.xml")
Sub [Challenge]: Optional("Day_15_challenge.xml")
----------------
Lume Program Day: Optional(1)
Main [Article]: Optional("Day_13_article.xml")
Sub [Quiz]: Optional("Day_13_quiz.xml")
----------------
```

ViewDidAppear Output:

```
--- ViewDidAppear ---
nil [None]
Warning: There are no phases in this program.
----------------
Lume Program Day: nil
Main [None]: nil
Sub [None]: nil
----------------
```

With the added didSet call, I only see it get called once, and it returns that the object does in fact exists. That line only gets written once, and I don't see any calls that state that it does not exist. Is there another variable call which I can add, such as didNullify or didEmpty?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another piece of code that's nullifying those properties?

Comment: I think I have found something, and it has to do with some of the overridden functions that I am calling. Will update my question with the code.

Comment: Hmm... that's strange behaviour, if the property is not nullified. Is the same view controller instance in both cases?

Comment: Yes, there might be another issue. Another developer working on this pointed out since this data is tied to CoreData. We are working through some ideas and I should have an update soon

Comment: I currently have exactly the same problem with some closures in a view I set on viewWillAppear, but no core data. Do you have any updates on this?